# .net Send Email with image in body not as attachment

Tags: .net, image, email

I am trying to create email with embedded images but do not want these images to appear as attachments. A have read multiple articles and followed the instructions but still my images get attached. My code:

```
public void SendFromTemplateWithImages(
        string recipients,
        string templateText,
        Dictionary<string, string> templateData = null,
        string replyTo = null,
        string bcc = null,
        bool replaceNewLinesWithHtml = true)
    {
        var messageTemplate = new MessageTemplate(
            templateText,
            templateData,
            replaceNewLinesWithHtml: replaceNewLinesWithHtml);

        ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(recipients, "recipients");
        ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(messageTemplate.Body, "body");

        recipients = recipients
            .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
            .Replace(";", ",");

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(recipients);
        message.Subject = messageTemplate.Subject;
        message.Body = messageTemplate.Body;
        message.AlternateViews.Add(GetAlternativeView(templateText));

        Send(message, true, replyTo: replyTo);
    }

    private AlternateView GetAlternativeView(string templateText)
    {
        var res = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Users\Borislav.Dimitrov\Desktop\screenShots\NewUser1_files\image001.png");
        res.ContentId = "logoID";
        var res2 = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Users\Borislav.Dimitrov\Desktop\screenShots\NewUser1_files\image002.png");
        res2.ContentId = "agroID";
        var res3 = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Users\Borislav.Dimitrov\Desktop\screenShots\NewUser1_files\image003.jpg");
        res3.ContentId = "linkedinID";
        var res4 = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Users\Borislav.Dimitrov\Desktop\screenShots\NewUser1_files\image004.jpg");
        res4.ContentId = "facebookID";
        var res5 = new LinkedResource(@"C:\Users\Borislav.Dimitrov\Desktop\screenShots\NewUser1_files\image005.jpg");
        res5.ContentId = "youtubeID";
        string htmlBody = templateText;
        AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res2);
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res3);
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res4);
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res5);
        return alternateView;
    }
```

Comment: You may need to specify the ContentType (Mime Type) for the email to display properly. I had inconsistent results with email client applications if the type was not included.

Comment: This is exactictly what I had to do and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<b> Should be HTML Body </b>";
```

Is this method "GetAlternativeView" returning HTML string ? It should be proper HTML which can be verified in browser.